# JQuery checkbox enable/disable using Jquery Mobile

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-mobile

During page load, I have a check box that is disabled. When pushing a button, I want it enabled. It works on my desktop version, but not on my jQuery Mobile version. If I do the opposite (enable on load and use the button for disable, it works just fine). Here is the code:

Html:

```
<div>
     @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Terms, new { id = "terms", disabled = "disabled"}) 
</div>

<div>
 <input type="button" id="blah" name="blah" data-inline="true" value="blah" />
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$().ready(function () {
    $("#blah").click(function () {            
        $('#terms').removeAttr('disabled');
    });
});
</script>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: I want to enable the check box using the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, [**you shouldn't use** `.ready()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14468659/jquery-mobile-document-ready-vs-page-events) in jQuery Mobile. Always use [jQuery Mobile events](http://api.jquerymobile.com/category/events/).

For your issue, you need to use `.prop('disabled, false)` and then call enhancement method `.checkboxradio('refresh')` to re-style the checkbox.

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/5fbJw/)**

```
$('#blah').on('click', function () {
  $('#foo').prop('disabled', false).checkboxradio('refresh');
});
```